# program that takes an input parameter as a string and return the alternate words in it with “abc”. Words are separated by dots

Tags: java, string

Write a function that takes an input parameter as a string and return the alternate words in it with “abc”. Words are separated by dots.
Note: Avoid using inbuilt functions

Input: "i.like.this.program.very.much"
Output: "i.abc.this.abc.very.abc"

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
public String func(String s) {
    String[] arr = s.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            arr[i]= "abc";
    }

    String rString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        rString += arr[i];
        rString += ".";
    }
    rString += arr[arr.length - 1];

    return rString;
}
```

Not my most efficient work, but it was what I came up with on the spur of the moment.

Comment: If one of these answers works for you, please select it as a correct answer

Comment: That split function(inbuilt) was exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean by avoiding built in methods, but this should work:

```
  public String whyNot(String s) {
     String[] sA = s.split("\\.");
     String newS = sA[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < sA.length; i=i+2) {
        newS += ".abc." + sA[i];
      }
     return newS;
  }
```

Comment: That split function(inbuilt) was exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: @RohiitKadam sounds like it's a homework :)

Comment: Implement your own split function by looping the string and add strings by delimeter in your case "." Then replace the function in the snippet

Answer (score -1):

**

public class Main

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String a="i.like.this.program.very.much.";


    String[]arr=a.split("\\.");


    for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){


        if(i%2==1)
            arr[i]="abc";
        
    }
    String rs="";


    for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){

          rs+=arr[i];

          rs+=".";
     }
    rs+=arr[arr.length-1];
    
    System.out.println(rs);
}
```

}

**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).